# Symfony2 global variable holding registration form

Tags: forms, symfony

I create and make available in Twig a User Registration form as follows:

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $registration = new Registration();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
    ));

    return $this->render(
        'RezialRezialBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

This works just fine. However, I want my Registration form to be available through a HTML button that persists along several pages on my website (typical Register button on site's topbar).

The issue here, is that this requires me to duplicate the above code creating the form to all the remaining controllers of my application!

Is there a way to make this registration form available through some sort of global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to [embed the controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). For example, if you have `somePage.html.twig`, in that page, you would do this:

```
{{ render(controller("AcmeBundle:ControllerName:register")) }}
```

Pay attention to that the embedding creates a **subrequest**. If you're not familiar with request stacks, you should read about that [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

Hope this helps...

Comment: When using subrequests, there is almost a mandatory caching requirement using something like Varnish. Otherwise your application will be very slow.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to write  it in all controller in your project,
you can call the controller in your base twig file

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:ControllerName:register' }}
```

in your base twig file

Comment: Jovan was a bit faster and more compete than you :) Still appreciated though!